# How to null check 2 selectors before continuing in ngrx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to null check 2 selectors, but I am unsure of how to do so.
I am not sure how to grab 2 selectors and pass filter them both
I want to do something like the following:
(isDefined is a fucntion that checks if null or empty)
Im new to rxjs, and I am still a bit confused on how to accomplish this.

```
this.store
  .pipe(
    select(fromSelector1.getSelector),
    select(fromSelector2.getSelector)
    filter(([select1, select2]) => isDefined(client) && isDefined()),
    tap(([client, user]) => {
      this.store2.dispatch(new action.Loading());
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: It's totally valid to use filter to check whether value is defined

Comment: Yes, but this does not work. How do I grab 2 selectors and pass them through?

Comment: Yeah, I was confusing about this implementation. I'm not sure if you can use two selector one by one.
But what you can do is to write one selector that will hold two of them.
Here is the reference where you can see actual implementation
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: These are for two different selectors

Answer (score 0):

Each selector looks like just normal stream to me, Maybe you can try

```
combineLatest(
    this.store.pipe(select(fromSelector1.getSelector))
    this.store.pipe(select(fromSelector2.getSelector))
).pipe(filter...
```